# Why can i not downcast UICollectionViewCell to a subclass thereof?

Tags: swift, casting, uicollectionview

I am making a collection view, and have made my own custom collectionCell. I have specified so in the identity inspector, and as far as i can tell, i have done everything right.

The code is

```
import UIKit

class SubjectCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

and in my collectionViewController

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubjectCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}
```

I get the following error message

"Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' (0x110460820) to 'project.SubjectCollectionViewCell' (0x10eceeda0).
(lldb)"

Comment: Are you sure you are dequeuing the correct cell? Make sure that reuse identifier is correct, and also that you set your custom cell class in the interface builder.

Answer (score 12):

refer to : [Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166364/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uicollectionviewcell)

if you see this in your collectionViewController, delete it.
`self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

Answer (score 3):

What happen is that in viewDidLoad(), Xcode automatically genere a line like this to define the cell:

> self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

And your are creating your own method to do this, so, you need to erase the line that was automatically generated by Xcode in the viewDidLoad()

Answer (score -2):

Did you register the reuseIdentifier so that it will create an object of the right class?

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. Should be posted as a comment.